# playlist management windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player, playlist

If, for example, I only want to play a song at index 3, 5, and 9 in media library, how can I do that?
My code is as follow:

```
private SongCollection mySongCollection;
```

Can I perform something like this:

```
mySongCollection = library.Albums[index].Songs + library.Songs[index];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `SongCollection` is an immutable class, you cannot directly instantiate it, add items to it and pass it to `MediaPlayer`. Instead, you could create an instance of `IEnumerable<Song>` and then iterate through it when passing the data to `MediaPlayer.Play`. For example, if you have two `SongCollection` instances, you could easily do this:

```
IEnumerable<Song> ultimateCollection = collection.Concat(collection2);
```

Where `collection` and `collection2` are of type `SongCollection`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, everything work out, however when I have ultimateColelction, how can I play that list? I use MediaPlayer.Play(ultimateCollection); but it seems not to be the right syntax

Comment: Because you cannot pass an instance of `IEnumerable` to `MediaPlayer`. You need to iterate through the enumeration (e.g. with the help of a `foreach` loop) and check the state of the `MediaPlayer` before advancing to the next song.

Comment: but if the user navigate from our app, then the check method is no longer valid, and the MediaPlayer would no longer play. Do you have a way to get around this? I have start a new question regard to this matter

Comment: @DenDelimarsky is it OK with we create another CustomSongCollection class ?

Comment: I don't see any way you can achieve this as SongCollection is a sealed and immutable class. No construction nor method of inserting/removing items from this class.